# how to handle date comparison in Java during daylight saving?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Not to run code at 5:30 Morning in Summer and not to run code on 6:30 in winter.

In Java Code, Applied following

```
scheduler (30 mins)
if(time.equals(5:30))
///exit code
```

but now winter comes and we need not not run it at 6:30 AM

How to handle this use case for daylight saving areas?

Comment: are you saying you *only* want to run the job in the summer, and not in the winter at all? Or just run it at the exact same real/true time (irrespective of winter/summer time) all year round?

Comment: Assuming that your time zone has a usual 1 hour summer time offset, 5:30 summer time corresponds to 4:30 standard time. Are you sure that you want 6:30 standard time? Which time zone is it?

Comment: Your Question is incomprehensible as currently written, as shown by the comments and attempts at answers. What does "not run code" mean? What does `(30 mins)` mean? I am voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TimeZone`'s `inDaylightTime()` method to determine if day light saving is applied or not e.g.

```
if(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska").inDaylightTime(new Date())){

   // when daylight is true

}
else{
   // Code when daylight saving is false

}
```

For machine's default time zone, you can check like

```
TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date())
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `ZoneId` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the actual library you are using here, so I can't provide a code example, but basically you could use `LocalDate` or something similar and configure it in your timezone. This would know about the daylight savings.